# Prove that Majorana mass term is Lorentz invariance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, dirac-matrices, chirality, majorana-fermions

I have a homework to prove that using one kind of chirality, let's say left-handed, we can construct a mass term. The argument is to show that this term $\psi^TCP_L\psi$ is satisfy the dimensionality of fermion mass, and further to show that it is Lorentz invariance.

I get stuck on this step to show that it is Lorentz invariance, particularly to resolve this thing $S_L^TCS_L$.
\begin{aligned}
\mathcal{L}^\prime & = (\psi^\prime)^TCP_L\psi^\prime \\
& =(S_L\psi)^TCP_LS_L\psi\\
& =\psi^TS_L^TC\frac{1}{2}(1-\gamma^5S_L)\psi \\
& =\psi^TS_L^TC\frac{1}{2}(1-S_L\gamma^5)\psi \\
& =\psi^TS_L^TCS_L\frac{1}{2}(1-\gamma^5)\psi \\
& =\psi^TS_L^TCS_LP_L\psi
\end{aligned}
Please anyone can elaborate more??

Note: $P_L$ is left-handed projection operator, $C$ is charge conjugation operator, and $S_L$ is Lorentz transformation operator, define as:
\begin{aligned}
S_L=1-\frac{i}{4}\sigma_{\mu\nu}\epsilon^{\mu\nu},
\end{aligned}
and
\begin{aligned}
\sigma^{\mu\nu}=\frac{i}{2}(\gamma^\mu\gamma^\nu-\gamma^\nu\gamma^\mu)
\end{aligned}